# Is it possible to share secrets, variables and reuse workflows in private organization with GitHub Team plan?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-secret, github-actions-reusable-workflows

Currently I use free plan for my organization, where each repo is private(and will remain such). My goal is to share secrets and variables over my organization and reuse workflows, instead of copying the workflow code and secrets into each repository. I understand that the Enterprise plan provides such functionality, though I couldn't find any clear information on Team plan, which is cheaper and preferrable, if it serves my needs.
Any help/hints will be much appreciated.